# Files in git working directory are empty but git doesn't see a diff

Tags: git

I've been working with git since 2008 and have never seen this. Fortunately, no edited files were affected and I was able to push a WIP, reclone, and soft reset, but I am hoping to avoid this in the future in case edit files get affected.

A bunch of source files - all in one particular directory - were all gull of nulls vhstd, i.e. 0x00. I could verify this with xxd. Thing is, `git status` didn't show any difference and when I copied over those files from another clone, then git said they were different. The diff showed file a as binary and file b as text. When I tried checking out HEAD for those specific files, I got no errors and even `git show HEAD -- <path>` showed nothing - no errors, no content. I found other questions about empty files, but these were errors from git saying the object was empty. I never once saw that. Seemingly, the git database was corrupt.

I was running git version 2.25.1.windows.1 and was using Visual Studio 16.5.2 at the time, which did seem to update Team Explorer because I had to sign into GitHub.

Has anyone seen this before and know what might've caused it? In hindsight, I should've ran `git fsck` but without any errors showing up, who knows if it would've helped.

Comment: "all empty, that is, full of nulls" Those are opposites. Which? An empty file contains no data. "Full of nulls" has data, namely a bunch of zeros.

Comment: "git status didn't show any difference" What does _that_ mean? difference between what and what? "When I tried checking out HEAD for those specific files, I got no errors" No, `checkout` will happily overwrite the file. "git show HEAD -- <path> showed nothing - no errors, no content" Because nulls have no printable avatar?

Comment: "empty" or "full of nulls" ? :-/ and "git status didn't show any difference" is what exact output ? aren't you using some alias ?

Comment: The output of shell commands about file content and status should help make this question more useful.

Comment: I'll edit the content. Thanks for getting hung up on entirely the wrong thing. As for output, that's just it: there was literally no error output from git. It just treated the files as if nothing was wrong. If there was an error, I would've posted it. I called that out in the description.